# Is there a way to directly access UICollectionView elements without reloading?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, reloaddata

I have another question open where I'm trying to figure out how to reload the collectionView without auto-scrolling.  I was also realizing there are a lot of other situations where I will need to change things in the collection view.  Also I have some items that I will want to change the .alpha on and change the text of.  Is there a way to do all of this in Swift?  For example (to be specific) if I have a collection view with a view in each cell and that view has a textField in it, can I change the alpha and text, (change alpha with animation even) without reloading entire table?

Comment: Did you try `reloadAtIndexPath`?

Comment: I know of it and was going to mention it but was also wondering if there is a way to go deeper and actually change a single item, like the way you can change a label or button normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the documentation for `UICollectionView`. There are several "reload" methods:

1. `reloadData()`
2. `reloadSections(_:)`
3. `reloadItems(at:)`

If you just want to reload a single item, update your data source's data and then call `reloadItems(at:)` passing in the index path for the item.

Another option, if a cell is currently visible, is to use the `cellForItem(at:)` method to get a reference to an existing cell. Then you can directly access UI components of the cell as needed. You should also update your data model as needed so if the user scrolls and comes back, the cell will be rendered properly.

Comment: Sorry the docs have lead me to a lot of dead ends and problems and confusion.  This is a great answer though ty CellForItem is what I was looking for and I think if I do both that and reloadItems I can accomplish what I'm trying to do :)

Answer (score 0):

Most appropriate where you can update your custom view of a particular UIcollectionViewcell is `reloadItemsAtIndexPaths`.
You would be handling a particular item than whole collectionview with `reloadData`.
You can handle it via notifications or some call backs in your code where you can make decision when to update which cell.

Hope it will help you.